# Are dust and clot simply metaphorical?

Tags: creation, creatures

In Jewish and Christian tradition, it is said that God created humans from dust. In Islam, it is said from a clot. Why is that difference? Are the two terms just metaphors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Islam it also says that Adam (hence humans) was created from dust. The clot (blood) is an intermediate stage which applies to a human fetus not Adam. Hence we are created from both.

> هو الذي خلقكم من تراب ثم من نطفة ثم من علقة ثم يخرجكم طفلا ثم لتبلغوا أشدكم ثم لتكونوا شيوخا ومنكم من يتوفى من قبل ولتبلغوا أجلا مسمى ولعلكم تعقلون
>
> It is He who created you from dust, then from a sperm-drop, then from a clinging clot; then He brings you out as a child; then [He develops you] that you reach your [time of] maturity, then [further] that you become elders. And among you is he who is taken in death before [that], so that you reach a specified term; and perhaps you will use reason.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 40:67](https://quran.com/40/67?translations=20)</sup>

Muslims understand it to be literal not metaphorical.